# How to make a button that sends the data in the cells next to it to another Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, button

I have a Workbook with multiple source sheets and one "output" sheet.

I would like to have a button on each row in the source sheets that copies the 7 cells to left of the button, convert them to a column and paste it to a specific place in the output sheet.

I´m struggling the most with the part of getting the function to know what cells it should select, as I must be able to copy the button to anywhere I want and still work.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

When I click the "POST" button, it doesn´t have to look like that but must be placed there, it should copy exactly the 7 cells to the left of the button, regardless of where the button ifself is...

[Source Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhVdc.png)

...and then paste them vertically into the C4 to C10 cells on the output Sheet

[Output Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5ReP.png)

I don´t need it to check or change the contents or anything like that

Comment: Do you have any script you are using as a starting point?  Sounds like checkboxes might be the best option here.

Comment: The Help instructions are pretty clear about this: **DO NOT post images of [] data, [], etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.** Please edit the question to include the data and the expected outcome in the body of the question.

Comment: I agree with @Codedabbler. Rather than use a button (which has the be laboriously copied into every sheet/cell) use a checkbox in each "POST" cell. Use an `onEdit` trigger and Event Objects to identify the sheet and the row, get the values, transpose then setValues in the Output sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You want to copy data from a nominated row on one of several sheets to an Output sheet. You have proposed using a button, but this answer uses a `checkbox`. When used with Event Objects, this will identify the edited sheet, edited row, edited column and edited value. This makes is easy to test to proceed or abort the function.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {

// Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

var sheetsToWatch = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"]
var outputSheetName = "Output"
var columnToWatch = 8 // column H

// Logger.log("DEBUG: edited column = "+e.range.columnStart+", sheet = "+e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()+", indexOf = "+sheetsToWatch.indexOf( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() )+", edited value = "+e.value+", edited row = "+e.rowStart)

// test for edit in Column H, in one of the named sheets and a value = true
if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch
      || sheetsToWatch.indexOf( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() ) === -1 
      || e.value !== 'TRUE')
  {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: do nothing")
    return
  }
  else{
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: do something")

    // define the data range for the values to be copied
    var sourceRange =  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: The source range = "+sourceRange.getA1Notation())
    var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues()
    // Logger.log(sourceData)

    // define the output range
    var targetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(outputSheetName).getRange("B1")
    // copy the data, and transpose the results
    sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
  }
}
```

---

**SAMPLE - INPUT Form**

[image: input]

---

**SAMPLE - OUTPUT**

[image: output]